# jQuery desconto na quantidade

Tags: jquery

tenho dois input um com valor e o outro com quantidade e span para resultado

```
<input type="text" value="50,00">
<input type="number" value="3">
<span id="resultado"></span>
```

preciso do seguinte eu sei fazer a multiplicacao dos input e o resultado. porem eu quero dar desconto a cada 3 produto. Se o cliente:

```
1) digitar 3 dou desconto de 1.
2) digitar 5 dou ainda dou desconto de 1.
3) digitar 6 dou desconto de 2. (entre na regra de acada 3 produtos vc ganha 1)
4) digitar 9 dou desconto de 3. (por causa da regra)
5) digitar 10 dou desconto de 3. (por causa da regra)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simples, pegue o resto da divisão por 3, se for zero quer dizer que pode dar desconto, depois e so pegar o total de produtos e dividir por 3 para dar a quantidade de produtos a terem desconto.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$("input[type=number]").change(function() {
  if (this.value % 3 === 0) {
    $("#resultado").html("<br><br>Produtos a dar desconto: " + this.value / 3);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" value="50,00">
<input type="number" value="3">
<span id="resultado"></span>
```